# Automatic installation using Debian with preseed inserted into initrd ignores keyboard configuration

Tags: debian, keyboard, debian-installer, preseed

This is my full `preseed.cfg`:

```
# Locales
d-i debian-installer/language string en_GB:en
d-i debian-installer/country string ES
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_GB.UTF-8


# Keyboard
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select es


# Network
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string preseed
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string


# Mirror
d-i mirror/country string ES
d-i mirror/http/hostname string deb.debian.org
d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i mirror/suite string stable


# Accounts
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password $1$EuB1h0/P$IIUGcTg79ZeX72l28Fh0E0
d-i passwd/user-fullname string preseed
d-i passwd/username string preseed
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password $1$N/qFSN1R$Ub33hbzjj4.jBhbygvN0P/


# Clock and time zone
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string Europe/Madrid
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true


# Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/vda
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select mypartitioning
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg00
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      mypartitioning ::                                       \
              512 1 512 xfs                                   \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs }     \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              1024 1 1024 linux-swap                          \
                      $defaultignore{ }                       \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      lv_name{ swap }                         \
                      in_vg { vg00 }                          \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               \
              3072 1 3072 xfs                                 \
                      $defaultignore{ }                       \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      lv_name{ root }                         \
                      in_vg { vg00 }                          \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs }     \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              6144 1 6144 xfs                                 \
                      $defaultignore{ }                       \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      lv_name{ var }                          \
                      in_vg { vg00 }                          \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs }     \
                      mountpoint{ /var }                      \
              .                                               \
              8192 1 1000000000 xfs                           \
                      $defaultignore{ }                       \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      lv_name{ home }                         \
                      in_vg { vg00 }                          \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs }     \
                      mountpoint{ /home }                     \
              .

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true


# Base system
d-i base-installer/kernel/image string linux-image-amd64


# Apt
d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect security, updates
d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.debian.org


# Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ssh-server
popularity-contest popularity-contest/participate boolean false


# Boot loader
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string default


# Finishing up
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

Installation completes successfully but the Spanish keyboard is not configured.
`/etc/default/keyboard` is not even created.

Things that I have tried but won't make a difference:

- Adjusting locale and language settings to meet keyboard settings. That is, using Spanish language and locale
- Using more keyboard definitions like variant, model, layout, no toggling, etc. No matter how further I specify the keyboard configuration, it won't work.

Things that I have noticed:

- This same preseed works 100% when using network installation, either storing the file in a web server or a PXE server. In those scenarios, the keyboard will be properly configured, which leads me to think that this preseed file is not the problem, has to be something else.
- A classmate showed me that you can change the keyboard by modifying the txt.cfg in isolinux, but this whole process is a bit messy and I still think you should be able to change the keyboard just modifying the preseed file

Here you have the full [/var/log/installer/syslog](https://pastebin.com/mz3Bm87j) of a created VM with this preseed file.

Do you think this is a d-i limitation or bug? Is there any actual way to make the keyboard config work using initrd preseeding by just modifying the preseed file? Why does it work over network installs but not with ISO?